# check for relationship duplicate numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

I 'm a programmer C# and look for one to **formulate mathematical** search numbers related to avoid duplicate relationships

I need to make a relationship of users in the database and for that I would not want to have a relationship repeated .

Sample:

I have an User A with the ID 10 and the user B with id 11.

In the table looks like this:

```
Coluna A|Coluna B
   10   |   11
```

Now I need to check if the 11 is already related to the 10 , because the table can not have a record with `11 | 10`.

I wonder if there is any way to do this check if there is already `10 | 11` or `11 | 10` .

I thought I'd sum, but would not work for `10 + 11 = 21` but also `20 + 1` .

PS . There will never be 10 | 10 , always different numbers .

Comment: Suppose sum works. How would you use it then? Store sums of already entered pairs into a hashtable? Also, can there be three pairs like $(10,11), (11,7), (7,10)$? And how large are your values - aren't they, by any chance, 32-bit integers?

Comment: @Abstraction, Are 64-bit integers

Comment: Well, doesn't matter. In your case, you need at least 127-bit type to have different values for any possible different pair; uniting values in `Tuple<Int64,Int64>` where first component is less than the second seems to be a suitable baseline solution (it already has `operator==()`, `GetHashCode()` and the like).